# Get Boolean and Integer values unquoted from Restful service in Glassfish v3

Tags: rest, jaxb, jersey, glassfish-3

I'm using the JaxRs Service to do RESTFul communication to the PHP Application.
My PHP colleges are complaining about the JSON formatting. The Boolean values are delivered as String and not as true or false only.

```
{ 
  "cusNO":"13493198",
  "elmFIRSTNAME":"John",
  "elmLASTNAME":"Smith",
  "elmCOMPANYNAME":"Acme",
  "addrSTREET":"Rock Street",
  "addrNO":"1",
  "cityID":"122704",
  "zipcodeID":"35525",
  "addrID":"12820372",
  "default":"true"
}
```

The web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>QISADS</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableXmlSecurity</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How can I tell the service not to use quotes for certain data types?

I saw that there is a possiblity to use non-string method in the JSONConfiguration but i looks like i need to explicitly setup each field of by entity bean to achive this.

I would prefer s.t. that works for all classes automatically. 
S.t. where I can define that all Boolean, Integer... must be non-string.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the web somewhere. It is very flexible but also you need to think about adding your classes into the array inside this class every time you add a new class into your project that will be transferred.

```
public class MyJsonProvider implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

private JAXBContext context;

private Class<?>[] types = { 
         MyFirstClass.class,
         MySecondClass.class
};

public MyJsonProvider() throws Exception {

    JSONConfiguration config = JSONConfiguration
        .natural()
        .humanReadableFormatting(true)
        .build();
    this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(config, types);
}

@Override
public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
    for (Class<?> c : types) {
        if (c.equals(type))
            return context;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}